# Installing Oracle Java on Linux Mint (instead of using OpenJDK) -- possible problems with linking

Tags: java, linux, linux-mint

I apologize in advance for the long query that'll follow, but I'm very lost and wanted to include all pertinent information.

Here is the system I started with:

```
Linux Mint 14 Nadia MATE
64-bit Kernel
OpenJDK version 1.7.0_21
```

I wanted to install Oracle Java 7 and have that be my system default.

Here is what I tried:

1) Downloaded tar file of JDK1.7.0_21
2) Unpacked and moved it into /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_21
3) `cd /usr/lib/jvm`
4) `ln -s  jdk1.7.0_21 java-7-oracle`
5) Created file `/usr/lib/jvm/.java-7-oracle.jinfo` and proceed to populate it with info such as:

```
    alias=java-7-oracle
    priority=50
    section=non-free

    jre ControlPanel /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/ControlPanel

    jre java /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/java
    jre java_vm /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/java_vm
    jre javaws /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/javaws  
    ....
```

6) Then, for some perhaps ill-thoughtout reasons, I abandoned this approach in favor of a shorter one that I felt I better understood. So I...

7) Deleted the symlink I had created  `rm java-7-oracle`  hoping that it would only remove the symlink.
8) Proceeded to execute the following commands:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.*/bin/java 1065
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/javac javac /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.*/bin/javac 1065
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/javaws javaws /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.*/bin/javaws 1065
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/jar jar /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.*/bin/jar 1065
```

9) `sudo update-alternatives --config java`
  And I picked this option:
`/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_21/bin/java  1065   manual mode`

Afterwards, when I ran `java -version` I got errors saying Java Virtual Machine could not be started.

Then, I went in and messed around a bit more, changed the priorities to 1, etc.. 
I even made the following changes to my `/etc/profile`:
         `JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_17`
         `PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin`
         `export JAVA_HOME`
         `export PATH`
And loaded it: `. /etc/profile`

But I still can't get java to work. 
The difference, though is that now when I run `java -version` I get:
    `bash: /usr/bin/java: No such file or directory`
I've also tried specifying the absolute path: `/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_21/bin/java -version`
But to no avail.

Can someone please help me? I feel quite lost at this point.
And I can't seem to revert back to OpenJDK either.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The problem, it turns out was that I was using a 32-bit version of Java with my 64-bit system.
So I removed `/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_21`

Then I went to Oracle and downloaded Java for Linux x64.
(I'd initially been mislead by their ambiguous "Java for Linux x86" labeling because my system was x86-64. Apparently their x86 refers to 32-bit systems.)

After downloading the correct 64-bit version, I followed the instructions from this site:

http://install-climber.blogspot.com/2013/02/linux-mint-14-nadia-mate-amd64-howto-install-oracle-java-jdk7.html

Answer (score 1):

**1. Check to see if your Ubuntu Linux operating system architecture is 32-bit or 64-bit**, open up a terminal and run the following command below.
Type/Copy/Paste: file /sbin/init
Note the bit version of your Ubuntu Linux operating system architecture it will display whether it is 32-bit or 64-bit.

**2. Check if you have Java installed on your system.** To do this, you will have to run the Java version command from terminal.
Open up a terminal and enter the following command:
Type/Copy/Paste: java -version
If you have OpenJDK installed on your system it may look like this:
java version "1.7.0_15"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.10pre) (7b15~pre1-0lucid1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 19.0-b09, mixed mode)
If you have OpenJDK installed on your system, you have the wrong vendor version of Java installed for this exercise.

**3. Completely remove the OpenJDK/JRE from your system and create a directory to hold your Oracle Java JDK/JRE binaries.** This will prevent system conflicts and confusion between different vendor versions of Java. For example, if you have the OpenJDK/JRE installed on your system, you can remove it by typing the following at the command line:

**Type/Copy/Paste:**

`sudo apt-get purge openjdk-\*`

This command will completely remove OpenJDK/JRE from your system

**Type/Copy/Paste:**

```
sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/java
```

This command will create a directory to hold your Oracle Java JDK and JRE binaries.

**4. Download the Oracle Java JDK for Linux.** Make sure you select the correctcompressed binaries for your system architecture 32-bit or 64-bit (which end in tar.gz).
For example, if you are on Ubuntu Linux 32-bit operating system download 32-bit Oracle Java binaries.
For example, if you are on Ubuntu Linux 64-bit operating system download 64-bit Oracle Java binaries.
Optional, Download the Oracle Java JDK Documentation
Select jdk-7u45-apidocs.zip
Important Information: 64-bit Oracle Java binaries do not work on 32-bit Ubuntu Linux operating systems, you will receive multiple system error messages, if you attempt to install 64-bit Oracle Java on 32-bit Ubuntu Linux.

**5. Copy the Oracle Java binaries into the /usr/local/java directory.** In most cases, the Oracle Java binaries are downloaded to: /home/"your_user_name"/Downloads.
32-bit Oracle Java on 32-bit Ubuntu Linux installation instructions:

**Type/Copy/Paste:**

```
cd /home/"your_user_name"/Downloads
```

**Type/Copy/Paste:**

```
sudo cp -r jdk-7u45-linux-i586.tar.gz /usr/local/java
```

**Type/Copy/Paste:**

```
cd /usr/local/java
```

64-bit Oracle Java on 64-bit Ubuntu Linux installation instructions:
**Type/Copy/Paste:**

```
cd /home/"your_user_name"/Downloads
```

**Type/Copy/Paste:**

```
sudo cp -r jdk-7u45-linux-x64.tar.gz /usr/local/java
```

**Type/Copy/Paste:**

```
cd /usr/local/java
```

**6. Run the following commands on the downloaded Oracle Java tar.gz files.** Make sure to do this as root in order to make them executable for all users on your system. 
**To open a root terminal type** 
`sudo -s you will be prompted for your logon password`.

32-bit Oracle Java on 32-bit Ubuntu Linux installation instructions:

**Type/Copy/Paste:**

```
 sudo chmod a+x jdk-7u25-linux-i586.tar.gz
```

64-bit Oracle Java on 64-bit Ubuntu Linux installation instructions:

**Type/Copy/Paste:**

```
sudo chmod a+x jdk-7u45-linux-x64.tar.gz
```

**7. Unpack the compressed Java binaries, in the directory /usr/local/java**
32-bit Oracle Java on 32-bit Ubuntu Linux installation instructions:

**Type/Copy/Paste:**

```
sudo tar xvzf jdk-7u25-linux-i586.tar.gz
```

64-bit Oracle Java on 64-bit Ubuntu Linux installation instructions:

**Type/Copy/Paste:**

```
sudo tar xvzf jdk-7u45-linux-x64.tar.gz
```

**8. Double-check your directories.** At this point, you should have two uncompressed binary directories in /usr/local/java for the Java JDK/JRE listed as:
**Type/Copy/Paste:** `ls -a`

*jdk1.7.0_45*

**9. Edit the system PATH file /etc/profile and add the following system variables to your system path.** Use nano, gedit or any other text editor, as root, *open up* `/etc/profile`.

**Type/Copy/Paste:**

```
sudo gedit /etc/profile
```

**or**
**Type/Copy/Paste:**

```
sudo nano /etc/profile
```

**10. Scroll down to the end of the file using your arrow keys and add the following lines below to the end of your /etc/profile file:**
**Type/Copy/Paste:**

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_45
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:$JAVA_HOME/bin
export JAVA_HOME
export PATH
```

**11. Save the `/etc/profile` file and exit.**

**12. Inform your Ubuntu Linux system where your Oracle Java JDK/JRE is located.** This will tell the system that the new Oracle Java version is available for use.

**Type/Copy/Paste:**

```
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "/usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_45/bin/java" 1
```

this command notifies the system that Oracle Java JRE is available for use

**Type/Copy/Paste:**

```
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javac" "javac" "/usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_45/bin/javac" 1
```

this command notifies the system that Oracle Java JDK is available for use

**Type/Copy/Paste:**

```
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javaws" "javaws" "/usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_45/bin/javaws" 1
```

this command notifies the system that Oracle Java Web start is available for use

**13. Inform your Ubuntu Linux system that Oracle Java JDK/JRE must be the default Java.**
**Type/Copy/Paste:**

```
 sudo update-alternatives --set java /usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_45/bin/java
```

this command will set the java runtime environment for the system

**Type/Copy/Paste:**

```
sudo update-alternatives --set javac /usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_45/bin/javac
```

this command will set the javac compiler for the system

**Type/Copy/Paste:**

```
sudo update-alternatives --set javaws /usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_45/bin/javaws
```

this command will set Java Web start for the system

**14. Reload your system wide PATH /etc/profile by typing the following command:**
**Type/Copy/Paste:**

```
. /etc/profile
```

Note your system-wide PATH /etc/profile file will reload after reboot of your Ubuntu Linux system

**15. Test to see if Oracle Java was installed correctly on your system. Run the following commands and note the version of Java:**

**16. A successful installation of 32-bit Oracle Java will display:**

**Type/Copy/Paste:**

```
java -version
```

This command displays the version of java running on your system
*You should receive a message which displays:*
java version "1.7.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_25-b25)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 23.1-b03, mixed mode)

**Type/Copy/Paste:**

```
javac -version
```

This command lets you know that you are now able to compile Java programs from the terminal.
*You should receive a message which displays:*
javac 1.7.0_25

**17. A successful installation of Oracle Java 64-bit will display:

**Type/Copy/Paste:**

```
java -version
```

This command displays the version of java running on your system
*You should receive a message which displays:*
java version "1.7.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_21-b21)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.6-b04, mixed mode)

**Type/Copy/Paste:**

```
 javac -version
```

This command lets you know that you are now able to compile Java programs from the terminal.
*You should receive a message which displays:*
javac 1.7.0_25

[https://www.wikihow.com/Install-Oracle-Java-JDK-on-Ubuntu-Linux][1]